# BGL iteration makros, typenames and templates

Tags: c++, templates, boost

In the bgl [iteration_makros.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/boost/graph/iteration_macros.hpp), it says

> Use the _T versions when the graph type is a template parameter or
>     dependent on a template parameter. Otherwise use the non _T versions.

e.g:

```
#define BGL_FORALL_EDGES_T(ENAME, GNAME, GraphType) \
for (std::pair<typename boost::graph_traits<GraphType>::edge_iterator, \
               typename boost::graph_traits<GraphType>::edge_iterator> BGL_RANGE(__LINE__) = edges(GNAME); \
  BGL_FIRST(__LINE__) != BGL_LAST(__LINE__); BGL_FIRST(__LINE__) = BGL_LAST(__LINE__)) \
  for (typename boost::graph_traits<GraphType>::edge_descriptor ENAME; \
    BGL_FIRST(__LINE__) != BGL_LAST(__LINE__) ? (ENAME = *BGL_FIRST(__LINE__), true):false; \
     ++BGL_FIRST(__LINE__))
```

vs.

```
#define BGL_FORALL_EDGES(ENAME, GNAME, GraphType) \
for (std::pair<boost::graph_traits<GraphType>::edge_iterator, \
               boost::graph_traits<GraphType>::edge_iterator> BGL_RANGE(__LINE__) = edges(GNAME); \
  BGL_FIRST(__LINE__) != BGL_LAST(__LINE__); BGL_FIRST(__LINE__) = BGL_LAST(__LINE__)) \
  for (boost::graph_traits<GraphType>::edge_descriptor ENAME; \
     BGL_FIRST(__LINE__) != BGL_LAST(__LINE__) ? (ENAME = *BGL_FIRST(__LINE__), true):false; \
     ++BGL_FIRST(__LINE__))
```

The only difference I see - and stackoverflow is kind enough to highlight this in the code - are the `typename` modifiers in the _T versions.

Now, I'm not terribly savvy about this whole typename and template thing, but why provide two versions at all? Why wouldn't the _T versions suffice? Could anybody give me an example where I cannot use the _T versions?

Or if there is no such example, what's the reasoning behind this?

On a related note, does using BGL's bundled properties count as the Graph's being "dependent on a template parameter"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With C++03 the `typename` keyword was allowed exactly where it was required. That is, if a dependent name referred to a type, it was necessary. If a type was not a dependent name, it was disallowed. Hence, depending on whether your are within a template or not, it may be allowed and required or not required and not allowed.

With C++11 the `typename` keyword is always allowed when referring to a nested type, i.e., with C++11 there is no longer any need for two versions and the `_T`-version is sufficient.